# How to fix AttributeError in Jupyter Lab with pre-written code?

Tags: python, jupyter, jupyter-lab, attributeerror, pexpect

I am new to Python and programming, and I am working on assignments for an IBM certificate course. These assignments are in `.ipynb` files, and much of the code is pre-written for us to run without editing. However, I am encountering an `AttributeError` related to the `pexpect` module when running various commands in Jupyter Lab.

Here is a minimal example of the code causing the error:

```
!wget https://url...
!mamba install bs4==4.10.0 -y
!pip3 install scikit-learn --upgrade --user
```

The error message I receive is:

```
AttributeError: module 'pexpect' has no attribute 'TIMEOUT'
```

I have tried restarting the kernel, using `urllib.request` as a workaround for `!wget`, and replacing `!` with `%`. I am running Jupyter Lab with Python 3.11.2.

How can I fix this AttributeError and run the pre-written code without issues?

Comment: Update: I seem to have fixed it by opening up jupyterlab through anaconda instead of directly accessing it through the web. If any other newbies are having trouble with this error when opening up lab assignments from the IBM courses, try anaconda!

Answer (score 0):

The `pexpect` module is maybe not installed or not imported correctly. Before execution, you can try installing it by running:

`!pip install pexpect`

in a Jupyter cell. If that doesn’t work, you can try importing it explicitly by adding `import pexpect` at the beginning of your code to confirm whether it is installed.

If you still get this error, try running these three commands in different Jupyter cells to know which command is failing for you:

```bash
!wget https://url...
!mamba install bs4==4.10.0 -y
!pip3 install scikit-learn --upgrade --user
```

**For your information:** ! and % symbols are used in Jupyter notebooks to run shell commands (bash) and magic commands, respectively. The !wget command is used to download files from the internet, while the !mamba and !pip3 commands are used to install Python packages.

Comment: @Jishah, some of your advice and information, especially in your section 'For your information' is outdated. Please, suggest using current best practices for installing inside modern Jupyter. The exclamation point is not recommended for use with pip install install when running inside a notebook. Use the magic version added to get around problems with the exclamation point (see [second paragraph here](https://discourse.jupyter.org/t/location-of-libraries-or-extensions-installed-in-jupyterlab/16303/2?u=fomightez) about that). Specifically, you should be ...

Comment: <continued>  advising `%pip install scikit-learn --upgrade --user`. The magic will also sort out which pip to use. I think it may also be `%mamba install` but you should verify that. I was surprised that now `%jupyter nbextension` works in a notebook lately and so maybe `%mamba install` is the current way as well. See [here](https://discourse.jupyter.org/t/why-users-can-install-modules-from-pip-but-not-from-conda/10722/4?u=fomightez) for more about the modern magic commands that overcome exclamation point shortcomings & install into the correct environment.

Comment: I just tried installing and importing pexpect in the first lines, which ran fine, but did not affect the error in any following lines. I did try %mamba and that gives an error that it's not a magic command. I also tried switching !pip3 to %pip and that also did not prevent the attribute error.

Comment: Thanks for the information about the `mamba` command not working with magic symbol.